# How to build opencv_contrib module for Android on windows

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, opencv, cmake

I'm working with opencv 3.2 on Android and everything is ok, but I need to use text detection where I found it into contrib module.

So I want to integreate contrib module to my opencv cv module in Android Studio but I can't find any tutorial to build opencv_contrib module for Android on Windows.

Any suggestion please? Thanks.

> PS : I have NDK and CMake installed and I downloaded the contrib module from  github
>   [opencv_contrib folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmxQp.png)

[image]